# Service don't want to register on Eureka with ssl

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I need to use my micro-service with https so I change my Eureka configuration like this :

```
info:
    component: Eureka
server:
    port: 8761
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        key-store: target/classes/keystore/keystore.jks
        key-store-password: .....
        key-alias: .....
        key-password: .....
        protocol: TLS
eureka:
    instance:
        hostname: localhost
        securePort: ${server.port}
        nonSecurePortEnabled: false
        securePortEnabled: true
        secureVirtualHostName: ${spring.application.name}
        homePageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/
        statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/admin/info
        metadataMap:
           hostname : ${eureka.instance.hostname}
           securePort: ${server.port}
    client:
        registerWithEureka: false
        fetchRegistry: false
        healthcheck:
            enable: true
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
    server:
        waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
        enableSelfPreservation: true
```

It start without problem and I can go on the web-site.

My micro-service (configServer) running on https but don't register on Eureka. I don't have error message. The configuration file :

```
info:
    component: Config Server
server:
    port: 8889
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        key-store: target/classes/keystore/keystore.jks
        key-store-password: .....
        key-alias: .....
        key-password: ....
        protocol: TLS
spring:
    cloud:
        config:
            server:
                git:
                    uri: .......
eureka:
    client:
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
        securePortEnabled: true
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: https://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
        healthcheck:
            enabled: true
    instance:
        statusPageUrlPath: https://${management.context_path}/info
        healthCheckUrlPath: https://${management.context_path}/health
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
        securePort: ${server.port}
        securePortEnabled: true  
        nonSecurePortEnabled: false
```

The log I get in Debug mode:

```
2016-11-29 10:47:35.324 DEBUG 12032 --- [freshExecutor-0] .a.h.i.c.DefaultClientConnectionOperator : Connecting to localhost:8761
2016-11-29 10:47:35.328 DEBUG 12032 --- [freshExecutor-0] o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  : Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@f63e34a closed
2016-11-29 10:47:35.328 DEBUG 12032 --- [freshExecutor-0] o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  : Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@f63e34a shut down
2016-11-29 10:47:35.328 DEBUG 12032 --- [freshExecutor-0] o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  : Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@f63e34a closed
```

Without https, I don't have problem. Do you have an idea of what is wrong ?

Comment: There's no error message? Have you turned on debug logging on the client?

Comment: Yes. I had the log in the main post

Answer (score 0):

your client has to be activated with

```
eureka: 
   client:
      enabled: true
```

which is missing in your config servers configuration.

Comment: It's not enough. If I'm not in ssl, I don't have the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: config server correctly registered over http but not over https (service is listed on Eureka but no host nor port is exposed).

Using spring-cloud-dependencies `Edgware.RELEASE` with `spring-cloud-commons` bumped to `1.3.1.RELEASE` and a self-signed certificate (added to my JREs cacerts).

Here is the config I use that works both over http (no profile set) and https (https profile)

service-discovery **application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=service-discovery
server.port=8161
server.ssl.enabled=false

eureka.instance.hostname=${DISCOVERY_HOSTNAME}
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.non-secure-port=${server.port}
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=false

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${DISCOVERY_SERVICE}
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

service-discovery **application-https.properties**

```
server.ssl.enabled=true

eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=false
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.secure-port=${server.port}
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl=https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/info
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl=https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/health
eureka.instance.homePageUrl=https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/

ribbon.IsSecure=true
```

config **bootstrap.properties**

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${DISCOVERY_SERVICE}
```

config **application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=config
server.port=8181
server.ssl.enabled=false

security.user.name=${SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_USERNAME}
security.user.password=${SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PASSWORD}
security.user.role=SYSTEM

eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.non-secure-port=${DISCOVERY_PORT}
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=false

eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
eureka.client.region=default
eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds=10

ribbon.IsSecure=true
```

config **application-https.properties**

```
server.ssl.enabled=true

eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=false
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.secure-port=${server.port}
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl=https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/info
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl=https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/health
eureka.instance.homePageUrl=https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/

ribbon.IsSecure=true
```

and here are the environment variables I use:

```
setx DISCOVERY_USERNAME "discoveryUser"
setx DISCOVERY_PASSWORD "change-me"
setx DISCOVERY_HOSTNAME "localhost"
setx DISCOVERY_PORT "8167"
setx DISCOVERY_SERVICE "http://${DISCOVERY_USERNAME}:${DISCOVERY_PASSWORD}@${DISCOVERY_HOSTNAME}:${DISCOVERY_PORT}/eureka/"

setx SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_URI "C:/change-me/spring-rest-oauth-config"
setx SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_USERNAME "configUser"
setx SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PASSWORD "change-me"
setx SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_DISCOVERY_SERVICE-ID "config"

rem something like "c:/users/ch4mp/.ssl/localhost-self-signed.p12"
setx SSL_KEY_STORE_PATH "change-me"

setx SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE file:%SSL_KEY_STORE_PATH%
setx SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD "change-me"
setx SERVER_SSL_KEY_ALIAS "spring-rest-oauth"
setx SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE PKCS12
```

please note that `DISCOVERY_SERVICE` scheme must be modified to `https` when using https profile

Comment: Initial comment wasn't an answer, it was just a ... comment. As I had the same question, I didn't post a new one. Just hoped this thread would come back in the pile. Now I found a solution, I edit it